# Confidence intervals for a normal fit in ggplot, cumulative probability

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval, cumulative-frequency

Edit: sorry I'm new to the community. I try to make it more clear with the sample data and code.

Here's the data (output of dput):

```
structure(list(`Sample Name` = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22), Type = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Size = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Height = c(270, 
280, 290, 295, 292, 285, 305, 330, 125, 130, 140, 142, 123, 117, 
140, 135, 132, 145, 160, 170, 136, 154)), row.names = c(NA, -22L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Now I used filter to categorize the data. I'm not sure if it's the smart way to do it, but works so far. Firstly,  two categories with two sizes of 1 and 3, then each size divide into two types : A and B. So at the end we have 4 kinds of data.

```
SizeOne <- filter (Alldata, Size== "1")
SizeThree <- filter (Alldata, Size== "3")

SizeonA <- filter (SizeOne, Type=="A")
SizeoneB <- filter (SizeOne, Type=="B")
SizeThreeA <- filter (SizeThree, Type=="A")
SizeThreeB <- filter (SizeThree, Type=="B")
```

Now this is the code to plot cumulative probability of 4 different categories. Then I used `stat_function` to add the Gaussian Distribution fit to each cumulative graph.

```
p2 = ggplot() + 
  stat_ecdf(data = SizeOne,aes(x= Height, color=SizeOne$Type),geom = "point", size = 1.2, linetype= "twodash", pad= FALSE)+  
  stat_ecdf(data = SizeThree,aes(x= Height, color=SizeThree$Type),geom = "point", size = 1 , pad= FALSE)+  
    scale_color_manual(values = c("#e73a00", "#002ee7"))+
    labs(title= "Cumulative probability", y = "Cumulative Probability", x= "Height") +



  stat_function(data= SizeThreeB, fun = pnorm, color="#e73a00" , args = list(mean=mean(SizeThreeB$Height), sd=sd(SizeThreeB$Height)))+
    stat_function(data= SizeThreeA, fun = pnorm, color="#002ee7" , args = list(mean=mean(SizeThreeA$Height), sd=sd(SizeThreeA$Height)))+
    stat_function(data= SizeoneB, fun = pnorm, color="#e73a00" , args = list(mean=mean(SizeoneB$Height), sd=sd(SizeoneB$Height)))+
      stat_function(data= SizeonA, fun = pnorm, color="#002ee7" , args = list(mean=mean(SizeonA$Height), sd=sd(SizeonA$Height)))



p2
```

1. Now my problem is how to add the confident intervals of 99%, 95% and 90% (bands) to the Gaussian fit? (not to the empirical cumulative).
2. Secondly how can I add error bars to the point of cumulative probability? (to the blue and blue points)

My plot so far

[image: My plot so far]

Comment: Please make the example reproducible. Can you post code and sample data? Please edit **the question** with the code you ran and the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please also add what  efforts you have made to search for a previous answer to the question and why the package documentation  did  not help you. This will help us to help you.

Comment: If I correctly understand, you want confidence intervals for the *cdf*. This question is better suited for CrossValidated.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for the comments. Now I have edited my question. Hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be safer to calculate the pnorm outside of ggplot. 
For your code, you don't need to filter. Keep the data as such and use ggplot's aesthetics and facets to group your data.

You can use the same groups to calculate the probability distributions, so that you can use the same aesthetics/facets in the probability plots.

**Disclaimer**

I am not a statistician. I just took the upper and lower confidence limits for your means and used this as the mean for the new pnorm calculation... This may not be correct. I agree with user @Stephane Laurent that you may get more correct answers how to calculate confidence intervals on CrossValidated.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(Rmisc)

split_data <- 
  alldata %>% 
  split(., interaction(.$Size, .$Type))

df_pnorm <- map(split_data, function(x){
  range_h <- range(x$Height)
  q <- seq(range_h[1], range_h[2])
  CI <- CI(x$Height)
  sd <- sd(x$Height)
  p_mean <- pnorm(q = q, mean = CI["mean"], sd = sd)
  p_lower <- pnorm(q = q, mean = CI["lower"], sd = sd)
  p_upper <- pnorm(q = q, mean = CI["upper"], sd = sd)
data.frame(Height = q, p_mean, p_lower, p_upper)
})  %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "size.type") %>%
  separate(size.type, c("Size", "Type"))

ggplot(alldata, aes(x = Height, color = Type, group = interaction(Type, Size))) + 
  geom_ribbon(data = df_pnorm, aes(ymin = p_upper, ymax = p_lower), alpha = 0.3)+
  geom_line(data = df_pnorm, aes(y = p_mean)) +
  stat_ecdf( geom = "point", pad= FALSE) +
  facet_grid(~ Size, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**data**

```
alldata <- structure(list(`Sample Name` = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
                                 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22), Type = c("A", 
                                                                                           "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
                                                                                           "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Size = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                                             1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Height = c(270, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                               280, 290, 295, 292, 285, 305, 330, 125, 130, 140, 142, 123, 117, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                               140, 135, 132, 145, 160, 170, 136, 154)), row.names = c(NA, -22L
                                                                                                                                                                                                               ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```